# How can I create 2D array dynamically?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cc

I'm trying to create 2d array however I'm getting error. Here's my code:

```
var cleanArr:Array = new Array();
for (var i:int = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    cleanArr[i][0] = arr[i].substring(0, 29);
    cleanArr[i][1] = arr[i].substring(29, int.MAX_VALUE);

    trace(cleanArr[i]);
}
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
>
> at SubtitleLoader/onComplete()[C:\Users\ ... \SubtitleLoader.as:88]
>
> at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
>
> at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
>
> at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()

Line 88: cleanArr[i][0] = arr[i].substring(0, 29);

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cleanArr is completely empty, it isn't a 2D array. For it to be a 2D Array, the items in it have to be Arrays. In Your code they do not exist at all. You have to create an array at the given position first. Try this:

```
var cleanArr:Array = new Array();
for (var i:int = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    cleanArr[i] = new Array();
    cleanArr[i][0] = arr[i].substring(0, 29);
    cleanArr[i][1] = arr[i].substring(29, int.MAX_VALUE);

    trace(cleanArr[i]);
}
```